# Number of keys that match a string

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{
  "day_mon"=>"on", "day_tue"=>"on", "day_wed"=>"on", "day_thu"=>"on",
  "day_fri"=>"on", "day_sat"=>"on", "day_sun"=>"on"
}
```

How can I count the number of keys in the hash that match the string `"day"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to create a temporary array:

```
h.count { |k,_| k.start_with?("day") }
  #=> 7
```

I've assumed that the key must begin with `"day"`, but if not:

```
h.count { |k,_| k =~ /day/ }
  #=> 7
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
h.keys.grep(/day/).count
```

**EDIT:** Because Cary Swoveland is completely correct,

```
h.each_key.lazy.grep(/day/).count
```

TIMTOWTDI :D

Answer (score 0):

- [Hash.keys](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keys) returns an array of the keys in `hash`
- [Array.select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) filters that array based on the regex `/day/`
- [Array.count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-count) counts the number of elements in the filtered array:

  `hash.keys.select { |key| key =~ /day/ }.count`